How do I get my sveltekit websocket ws to work on IIS?
I am trying to get my sveltekit websocket app to run on IIS on my server running Windows server 2022. I cloned the project form this repository which uses the node ws library. After I build the project and run the preview version it works on my local machine. I think it has to do with the server.cjs file and the web.config file that I have in my build folder on the server, but I really do not know. I see there is a prodServer.ts that is in the root directory. I can not find any of this code in the build folders so It's possible that I need to put this folder or reference it in the build folder on my server. I appreciate any help or guidance in advance.
Also if someone has another working repo with websockets in sveltekit that they know will work with IIS I would love to see that project.
Server.cjs
process.env.SOCKET_PATH = process.env.PORT;
delete process.env.PORT

import('./index.js')


web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.cjs" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="node">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.cjs" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;*.cjs" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

